# Is there a way to redefine the navigation keys for tmux copy mode?

Tags: tmux

When in tmux copy mode, I'd like to move the cursor with some Alt+key combos rather than the arrows. Is there a way to make tmux do this?

Here are the definitions I'd like:

```
Alt+i: up
Alt+l: right
Alt+j: left
Alt+k: down
Alt+o: forward word
Alt+u: backward word
```

I do not want to switch tmux over to vi mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to edit the key bindings for the `emacs-copy` table. Here's how I made the changes that I wanted above.

First, I checked out what the current bindings were by entering the following command in tmux (by pressing Prefix+colon) `list-keys -t emacs-copy`. This gave me a list of the keys that were bound in *emacs-copy* mode and I looked through them to figure out which commands did what I wanted.

Then, I added the appropriate key bindings to my ~/.tmux.conf file like so:

```
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-j cursor-left
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-i cursor-up
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-l cursor-right
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-k cursor-down
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-u previous-word
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-o next-word
```

Finally, I ran the tmux command `source ~/.tmux.conf` inside tmux to get the keys bound without having to exit and reload the session.

Answer (score 1):

This (apparently) has changed in more recent tmux versions: In `2.9a`, there does not seem to be an `emacs-copy` key table (but there's a `copy-mode`), and the `bind-key` argument for key tables is (only) `-T` (note upper case).  So to e.g. have Ctrl-Left/Right jump words in copy/mode:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode C-Left send-key -X previous-word                                                                  
bind-key -T copy-mode C-Right send-key -X next-word
```